# How can I suppress Ant warnings for overrided properties?

Tags: ant

I have build.xml with some global properties:

```
<project default="build">
  <property environment="env"/>
  <property name="root.dir" location=".."/>
  <property name="subdir.dir" location="${root.dir}/subdir"/>
  ...
</project>
```

My builds work fine but every time I do an `<antcall>`, I get a mess of override warnings for these global properties:

```
Override ignored for property "env.VAR1"
Override ignored for property "env.VAR2"
Override ignored for property "root.dir"
...
```

I get them even though I haven't actually overridden the properties in the task. The warning messages have made my ant log very verbose and hard to follow. Is there a way to suppress the warnings?

I'm using ant 1.9.4, which I can upgrade if needed.

Comment: If you don't specify inheritAll=false when using anthill, by default all properties are passed to the child project, hence the messages.  Adding inheritAll=false will prevent that.  It should be OK if you are specifying all the properties at the top-level.

Comment: @martinclayton I just have a single build.xml file. No higher level any file calling it. Is there a way to specify this parameter? I don't see it on "project" or as an ant option.

Comment: Sorry - my spell check mangled the comment - the parameter goes on the antcall task not the project.  See https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/antcall.html